# How to get a child node of a particular parent node in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an input something like this:

```
<applicationData>
<product>
 <productCode>ABC</productCode>
 <actionType>NW</actionType>
 <product>
  <productCode>66890</productCode>
  <actionType>NW</actionType>
   <product>
    <productCode>66889</productCode>
    <actionType>NW</actionType>
   </product>
    <product>
    <productCode>66566</productCode>
    <actionType>NW</actionType>
   </product>
 </product>
</product>
</applicationData>
<applicationData>
 <product>
  <productCode>66813</productCode>
  <actionType>NC</actionType>
   <product>
    <productCode>66788</productCode>
    <actionType>RM</actionType>
   </product>
 </product>
</applicationData>
```

Each applicationData has different levels of product. How do i get all the productcodes of the last level of product?

The first applicationData is having 3 levels of product whereas, the second one is having 2 levels.

For example, i would need to check if productCode = 66889 and productCode=66566 . How do i achieve this in XSLT ? what would be the XPath ?

I tried something like this :

```
applicationData/product[..//productCode='66889' and ..//productCode='66566']
```

But doesnt help. Please help.

Comment: The expression that you tried seems to be using `/` and `//` with no understanding of what they mean, suggesting that you need to do some more reading.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i get all the productcodes of the last level of product?

If by "last level of product"" you mean a product that does not have a child product, you would be looking for:

```
//product[not(product)]/productCode
```

See the demo [here](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2Froot%22%3E%0A%09%3Cresults%3E%0A%09%09%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22%2F%2Fproduct%5Bnot%28product%29%5D%2FproductCode%22%2F%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fresults%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Croot%3E%0A%09%3CapplicationData%3E%0A%09%09%3Cproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CproductCode%3EABC%3C%2FproductCode%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CactionType%3ENW%3C%2FactionType%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CproductCode%3E66890%3C%2FproductCode%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CactionType%3ENW%3C%2FactionType%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3Cproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3CproductCode%3E66889%3C%2FproductCode%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3CactionType%3ENW%3C%2FactionType%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%2Fproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3Cproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3CproductCode%3E66566%3C%2FproductCode%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3CactionType%3ENW%3C%2FactionType%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%2Fproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%3C%2Fproduct%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Fproduct%3E%0A%09%3C%2FapplicationData%3E%0A%09%3CapplicationData%3E%0A%09%09%3Cproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CproductCode%3E66813%3C%2FproductCode%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CactionType%3ENC%3C%2FactionType%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cproduct%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CproductCode%3E66788%3C%2FproductCode%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3CactionType%3ERM%3C%2FactionType%3E%0A%09%09%09%3C%2Fproduct%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Fproduct%3E%0A%09%3C%2FapplicationData%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML).